# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'const char *'

Tags: c

I have the following code which is failing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1) and has the following warning:

Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'const char *'

```
char *printb(fmt,a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10)
{
    static char string[256];
    sprintf(string,fmt,a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10);
    return(string);
}
```

printb is being called by this code:

```
    if (gotargs) fname = *(argv++);
    else do {
        printf("file name #%d: ", i+1);
        fname = gets(inbuf);
    } while (*fname == 0);
    if ((gbuf=fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL)
        error(printb("I can't find '%s'", fname));
    printf("reading '%s'...\n", fname);
    if (fgets((lp = inbuf), 512, gbuf) == NULL)
        error("file is empty");
```

Also, how can I convert the gets() to fgets() properly?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't declared the types of your `printb()` function parameters. Was that deliberate, or are you very new to C?

Comment: It's been a while since I've written C, and this code itself is ancient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, why did you use the ancient-style function declaration

```
char *printb(fmt,a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10)
{
```

?

This declaration declares all arguments as `int`s. Your attempts to pass a `char *` pointers to this function will only lead to disaster. Moreover, you are not supplying all parameters in your `printb` calls, which is another disaster.

It looks like you are attempting to implement a function with variable number of arguments. Specifically for that the language supports `...` parameter declaration. Read about variadic functions and `va_list`.

Your function would be implemented along the lines of

```
char *printb(const char *fmt, ...)
{
   static char string[256];
   va_list va;

   va_start(va, fmt);
   vsprintf(string, fmt, va);
   va_end(va);

   return string;
}
```

or better

```
   ...
   vsnprintf(string, sizeof string, fmt, va);
   ...
```

Although the idea of returning a pointer to an internal static buffer is also flawed.

Meanwhile, trying to "emulate" variadic arguments by your method is hopeless. It won't work.

Comment: so char *printb(char *fmt,a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10) is what I want?